# Restrict Apache Solr access in Glassfish. Basic Authentication vs. Firewalling

Tags: authentication, solr, glassfish, firewall, solrj

I have an [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) instance deployed in Glassfish and I am using this Solr instance from Java code via [Solrj](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj). The thing is, that I want to restrict access to Solr so that just this Java code can access it (the code can run from different IP addresses).

My first thought was to change the `web.xml` of my deployed Solr instance to add Basic Authentication using a Glassfish's file-based Realms, because I used this to restrict access to a REST interface in another project. So I've added the following lines into the Solr web.xml:

```
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Secure</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      <http-method>GET</http-method>
      <http-method>POST</http-method>
      <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
      <http-method>PUT</http-method>
      <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
      <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
      <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <description>has to be a USER</description>
      <role-name>USERS</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>

  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>userauth</realm-name>
  </login-config>

  <security-role>
    <role-name>USERS</role-name>
  </security-role>
```

But somehow this thing doesn't work for Solr access. I don't get the authentication dialog, which is pretty weird, because it worked in another setup.

In general, is this way of protecting a Solr instance a good approach or should I try another one? In the [Solr Security page](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrSecurity), they talking about firewalling the Solr instance. I am not a Linux admin, but I think iptables would be a possible solution and there are some nice answers on *serverfault* (e.g. [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/248384/allow-iptables-to-allow-ip-range-only-on-specifc-port)).

What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, my solution was really to use firewalling instead of modifying Solr in some way.